# Typescript non function prop names not working with alias

Tags: typescript

i use this to get the type containing all of the non function prop names for my class.

```
export type NonFunctionPropNames<E> = {
  [K in keyof E]: E[K] extends Function ? never : K;
}[keyof E];
type NonFunctionProps<E> = Pick<E, NonFunctionPropNames<E>>;
```

It works really good, but lately i started using alias names for some of my classes and it fails. I have static method to get prop with some prefix (or list of them with prefixes).

```
static getPropsWithPrefix<K extends keyof NonFunctionProps<Entity>, P extends K | K[]>(prop: P): 
  P extends string ? string : string[] {
  ....
}
```

If i call it like this -
`Entity.getPropWithPrefix('propName')` It works good, but when i add alias `ALIAS.Entity.getPropWithPrefix('propName')` It shows warning in IDE - `Argument type "propName" is not assignable to parameter type (keyof NonFunctionProps<Entity>)[] | keyof NonFunctionProps<Entity>`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] others can paste as-is into their own IDEs to see what you're seeing without introducing unrelated problems.  This will let others get to work on the issue immediately and test against a common baseline.